# USB 3 flash drives disconnect wifi. Any workaround?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb-3

I'm on a Dell Precision 7560 running Ubuntu 20.4 installed by Dell. Inserting flash drives that are USB 3 disconnect me from wifi and won't allow me to reconnect while the stick is plugged in. Inserting flash drives that are USB 2 don't cause this problem. Drivers are updated.

Is there a workaround for this, other than not using USB 3 flash drives while using wifi? Thank you!

Comment: Presumably you are using the USB A ports on the laptop. Do you have any way to attach the USB 3 flash drive via the USB C ports on the other side? I'm not saying it will work, but it is worth trying. Or could you use 5 GHz WiFi instead of 2.4 GHz?

Comment: Interesting problem I've not encountered. 1. Have you tried an old USB 2.0-only hub for USB 3.0 devices, which are backwards compatible? 2. USB 3.0 can supply more current than USB 2.0. Perhaps power is marginal, insufficient for WiFi card -- in that case, a *powered* USB 3.0 hub might work.

Comment: Thank you for the input! Yes, I tried running on 5 GHz and it was difficult to get the machine to stay on 5 GHz. I'm running the laptop wifi with "Managed" mode and the router where I am likes to switch to 2.4 GHz, and I don't access to change the router settings. I'll try switching to "Ad-Hoc" and see if I can keep the machine on 5 GHz and see if that will do it. Yes, I can try buying a hub to plug into the USB C or A ports.